# Error de Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, jquery

El siguiente código:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tecnliv/core/init.php';
$padreID = (int)$_POST['padreID'];
$selected = sanitize($_POST['selected']);

$childQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `categorias` WHERE padre = '$padreID' ORDER BY nombre");

ob_start(); ?>
 <option value =""></option>
 <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($childQuery)): ?>
 <option value="<?=$child['id'];?>" <?=(($selected == $child['id'] )?' lected':'');?>><?=$child['nombre'];?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Devuelve el error:

> Notice: Undefined index: padreID in C:\xampp\htdocs\tecnliv\admin\parsers\child_categorias.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\tecnliv\admin\parsers\child_categorias.php on line 4

Comment: Bienvenido. Unas palabras introductorias nunca vienen mal. Los avisos (notice) que tienes indican que en tu URL actual no hay nada llamado `padreID` ni nada llamado `selected`. La URL debe ser algo así más o menos: `child_categorias.php?padreID=1&selected=true`

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está pidiendo hacer el debugging sin mostrar ningún tipo de investigación por su parte.

Answer (score 1):

Estos `NOTICE` aparecen por que no estan definidas las variables indicadas, en este caso es debido a que **no se enviaron esas variables** por `POST`.

Puedes validar si se recibieron datos o no de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST['padreID']) OR !empty($_POST['selected']) ) {
  // se recibieron datos POST
  $padreID = (int)$_POST['padreID'];
  $selected = sanitize($_POST['selected']);
}
else{
    // NO se recibieron datos POST
    echo 'NO se recibieron datos POST';
    // detenemos la ejecución
    exit;
}
```

En lugar de cortar la ejecucion tambien podrias declarar unos valores por defecto cuando no se reciban datos y continuar la ejecución, dependiendo de lo que necesites:

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST['padreID']) OR !empty($_POST['selected']) ) {
    // se recibieron datos POST
    $padreID = (int)$_POST['padreID'];
    $selected = sanitize($_POST['selected']);
}
else{
    // NO se recibieron datos POST
    // asignamos valores por defecto
    $padreID = 1;
    $selected = 'lo que sea';
}
```